# Some times if I run my tests the lib files are gone from my Output folder, Can someone tell me the reason?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, dll

If I run or debug test, this test working but I can't run my main project because lib file not found. If rebuild solution it works.

```
 [TestMethod]
 public void MyTestMethod()
 {
     Assert.AreEqual(2, 2 + 2);
 }
```

If run project I get this error:

> There were 3 error(s) during build. Details: error CS0006: Metadata
>   file 'OpenAccessAssemblies\Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions.dll' could
>   not be found error CS0006: Metadata file
>   'OpenAccessAssemblies\Telerik.OpenAccess.dll' could not be found The
>   system cannot find the file specified Inner Exception: There were 3
>   error(s) during build. Details: error CS0006: Metadata file
>   'OpenAccessAssemblies\Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions.dll' could not
>   be found error CS0006: Metadata file
>   'OpenAccessAssemblies\Telerik.OpenAccess.dll' could not be found The
>   system cannot find the file specified

I think problem in visual studio incremental clean. Some times visual studio incremental clean run and lib file deleted. How I can stop visual studio incremental clean?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please provide the actual error message.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the error messages there so we can read them easily.

Comment: How are these assemblies being referenced by your test project - are they directly referenced or as a result of some runtime composition or IOC ?